# Widget with ListView in API 4

Tags: android, android-widget

I already know that `ListView` is **not supported** in widgets until `HoneyComb`. But Foursquare's widget uses `ListViews` even on API 4 (see the picture).

Is there any way to implement `ListView` for Widgets in API 4? I've searched document and more nothing mentioned about ListView in Widgets.

When I tried to use, always got inflating error.

I'm curious about suggestions and examples.

[image: Foursquare widget]

Comment: Is it an actual listview that you scroll by flicking on the rows? Or do you change to the next set of three using the arrows at the top of the picture.

Comment: @metalideath You're right, I can change the next set of three by using the arrows. So is it not a real ListView? If yes, are they all just simple ImageViews and TextViews?

Comment: Yup... its just ImageViews and TextViews and Hidden views for alignment purposes and to get the row borders and list borders to look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something similar to this in one of my widgets. Listview is not supported in API 4, and while this "looks" like a ListView it is not. Its just cleverly positioned images, and text and a border around them that looks like a ListView does.

The arrows are images that when clicked tell the widget to go rerender all the stuff in the "ListView". So it sort of gives an approximation of a ListView on older devices, but you need to use arrows to change the content instead of flicking on the ListView.

Comment: Gotcha, But still I missed something about arrows. What's the way of rerender content by using arrows. ViewFlipper is also not supported, so do I change all stuff by manuel. I mean TextView by TextView. Can't I iterate it? Thank you.

Comment: Basically to support the arrows you need to register each arrow with a click callback. Then when it runs get references to all the GUI elements. So looking at this image each row has 4 GUI elements that you need to get handles to. Then lookup the content for your new "screen" and update the content of each of those GUI elements. You can make a function that can render one row and just call it three times with pointers to the 4 GUI elements for a row.